# using 2 different modems with two Ethernet ports simultaneously

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

we have two modems 1 for internet and the other for VPN to other server.  the problem i faced is internet works when disable the VPN network and i can only connect to VPN server when disabling the internet network. how can manage them to work together simultaneously. i'm not that much a networking guy. Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: Use a VPN Client-Server App that supports Split Tunnel.

Comment: See https://techijack.com/what-is-vpn-split-tunneling-vpn-setup-on-server-2019/